# jquery localization issue with .NET 4.5 Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, localization

I have a .NET 4.5 .ascx control that renders html and a jquery script on the client page (server side, of course). I am currently localizing the site this control belongs to (haven't gotten to this control yet) and am experiencing some strange issues when changing the language(s) in IE9.

The control looks and works fine, when the browser language is set to ENGLISH. However when it's changed to any other language, the control does not respond to any of the jquery events. It renders as it should, and everything LOOKS good.. it just won't respond to any mouse over / out or click events.

If I set the browser language back to ENGLISH, everything works fine. Is there something I am missing?

Here is the control code (the .ascx page is just an asp.net literal) and the jquery script that it renders along with it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;

using MyCode.DBS.DataEntities;
using MyCode.DBS.BusinessCore;
using MyCode.DBS.Utilities;

namespace MyCode.DBS.WebCore.Controls
{
    public partial class MetroTiles : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        // Global Crypto Key
        private string CRYPTO_KEY = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Application["CRYPTO_KEY"]);
        // Get Framework Image Location
        private string IMAGE_LOC = Convert.ToString(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HDBSFrameworkImages"]);
        // Ratio of normal slide height (or width for horz) to tile height.
        private const decimal SLIDE_HW_RATIO = .3m;
        // Ratio of extended slide height (or width for horz) to normal slide height.
        private const decimal SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO = .5m;
        // Slide icon cell reservation size
        private const int SLIDE_ICON_CELL_SZ = 40;

        // TESTED 09/27/2013 - PASSED! - B. Nichols
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MetroTileGroup group = null;
            StringBuilder sb_HTML = null;
            int grpCellHeight = 0;
            int grpCellWidth = 0;
            int grpMarginTop = 0;
            int grpMarginLeft = 0;

            int tileCellHeight = 0;
            int tileCellWidth = 0;
            int tileHeight = 0;
            int tileWidth = 0;

            string tileCellSpan = string.Empty;
            string tileClass = string.Empty;
            string tileID = string.Empty;
            string tileCursorStyle = string.Empty;
            string tileBkGrndStyle = string.Empty;
            string tileSlideBkGrnd = string.Empty;
            bool tileActive = false;

            int tileSlideHeight = 0;
            int tileSlideWidth = 0;
            int tileSlideExt = 0;
            string tileSlideTable = string.Empty;
            string tileSlideMargin = string.Empty;

            int currentRow = 0;
            int prevRow = 0;

            try
            {
                // Check existance of CRYPTO_KEY
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CRYPTO_KEY))
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Application Encryption Key Not Found");

                // Get Tile Group & Associated Tiles
                group = Support.GetMetroGroup(this.TileGroupID, WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[this.ConnectionStringName], CRYPTO_KEY);
                if (group != null)
                {
                    // Set Tile Cell Dimentions (Group Table)
                    grpCellHeight = group.MetroStdTileHeight + (group.MetroBorderSize * 2) + (group.MetroMarginSize * 2);
                    grpCellWidth = group.MetroStdTileWidth + (group.MetroBorderSize * 2) + (group.MetroMarginSize * 2);

                    // Set TOP and LEFT Margins for Tile Group (Center)
                    grpMarginTop = (grpCellHeight * group.MetroGroupRows) / 2;
                    grpMarginLeft = (grpCellWidth * group.MetroGroupColumns) / 2;

                    // Initiate Group (Table) Layout
                    // Set Group Header
                    sb_HTML = new StringBuilder();
                    sb_HTML.AppendFormat("<table style=\"position: relative; top: 40%; left: 50%; margin: -{0}px 0 0 -{1}px; border-collapse: collapse\">\n",
                                         grpMarginTop.ToString(), grpMarginLeft.ToString());
                    sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t<tr>");
                    sb_HTML.AppendFormat("\t\t<td style=\"font: normal 1.4em 'Segoe UI Light'; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px\" colspan=\"{0}\">\n",
                                         group.MetroGroupColumns.ToString());
                    sb_HTML.AppendFormat("\t\t\t{0}\n", Server.HtmlEncode(group.MetroGroupHeader));
                    sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t\t</td>");
                    sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t</tr>");

                    // Set Individual Tiles
                    foreach (MetroTileItem tile in group.MetroGroupTiles)
                    {
                        // Set current row counter
                        currentRow = tile.TileItemRow;

                        // Check if table row tags need closed or opened (
                        if (!currentRow.Equals(prevRow))
                        {
                            // Close previous row tag (If not first row)
                            if (!prevRow.Equals(0))
                                sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t</tr>");
                            sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t<tr>");
                        }

                        // Get tile size by tile type
                        switch (tile.TileItemType)
                        {
                            case MetroTileType.Square:
                                tileID = string.Format("sTile_{0}", tile.TileItemID.ToString());
                                tileCellHeight = grpCellHeight;
                                tileCellWidth = grpCellWidth;
                                tileHeight = group.MetroStdTileHeight;
                                tileWidth = group.MetroStdTileWidth;
                                tileCellSpan = string.Empty;
                                break;
                            case MetroTileType.Vertical:
                                tileID = string.Format("vTile_{0}", tile.TileItemID.ToString());
                                tileCellHeight = grpCellHeight * 2;
                                tileCellWidth = grpCellWidth;
                                tileHeight = (group.MetroStdTileHeight * 2) + (group.MetroMarginSize * 2) + (group.MetroBorderSize * 4);
                                tileWidth = group.MetroStdTileWidth;
                                tileCellSpan = "rowspan=\"2\"";
                                break;
                            case MetroTileType.Horizontal:
                                tileID = string.Format("hTile_{0}", tile.TileItemID.ToString());
                                tileCellHeight = grpCellHeight;
                                tileCellWidth = grpCellWidth * 2;
                                tileHeight = group.MetroStdTileHeight;
                                tileWidth = (group.MetroStdTileWidth * 2) + (group.MetroMarginSize * 2) + (group.MetroBorderSize * 4);
                                tileCellSpan = "colspan=\"2\"";
                                break;
                        }

                        // Get tile hover effect
                        switch (tile.TileItemEffect)
                        {
                            case MetroTileHoverEffect.None:
                                break;
                            case MetroTileHoverEffect.Slide:
                                tileClass = "slideTile";
                                tileSlideBkGrnd = tile.TileItemForeground;
                                break;
                            case MetroTileHoverEffect.VerticalAxisFlip:
                                tileClass = "vertFlipTile";
                                break;
                            case MetroTileHoverEffect.HorizontalAxisFlip:
                                tileClass = "horzFlipTile";
                                break;
                        }

                        // Determine if tile is hyperlinked.
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tile.TileItemURL))
                        {
                            tileClass += " activeTile";
                            tileCursorStyle = "cursor: pointer;";
                            tileActive = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tileCursorStyle = string.Empty;
                            tileActive = false;
                        }

                        // Determine if blank (empty) tile
                        if ((!tileActive) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tile.TileItemLabel)) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tile.TileItemIcon)))
                            tileClass = "blankTile";

                        // Determine tile background
                        if (tile.TileItemBackground.StartsWith("#"))
                            tileBkGrndStyle = string.Format("background-color: {0};", tile.TileItemBackground);
                        else
                            tileBkGrndStyle = string.Format("background: url('{0}') center no-repeat;", tile.TileItemBackground);

                        // Initialize Row Cell
                        sb_HTML.AppendFormat("\t\t<td style=\"width: {0}px; height: {1}px\" {2}>\n", tileCellWidth.ToString(), tileCellHeight.ToString(), tileCellSpan);

                        // Start Cell Tile
                        sb_HTML.AppendFormat("\t\t\t<div class=\"{0}\" id=\"{1}\" style=\"{2} width: {3}px; height: {4}px; position: relative; " +
                                             "margin: {5}px; border: {6}px solid {7}; {8}\">\n", tileClass, tileID, tileBkGrndStyle, tileWidth.ToString(),
                                             tileHeight.ToString(), group.MetroMarginSize.ToString(), group.MetroBorderSize.ToString(), group.MetroBorderColor, tileCursorStyle);

                        // Add tile effects if not a blank tile
                        if (!tileClass.Equals("blankTile"))
                        {
                            // ** SLIDE TILES **
                            if (tile.TileItemEffect.Equals(MetroTileHoverEffect.Slide))
                            {
                                // Find slide margin by tile type and slide size;
                                switch (tile.TileItemType)
                                {
                                    case MetroTileType.Square:
                                    case MetroTileType.Vertical:
                                        tileSlideHeight = (int)Math.Round(tileHeight * SLIDE_HW_RATIO);
                                        tileSlideWidth = tileWidth;
                                        tileSlideExt = (int)Math.Round((tileSlideHeight * SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO) + tileSlideHeight);
                                        tileSlideMargin = "bottom: 0px;";
                                        tileSlideTable = string.Format("\t\t\t\t\t<table style=\"width: {0}px; height: {1}px; border-collapse: collapse\">\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"width: {2}px; height: {3}px; font: normal 0.95em 'Segoe UI Semibold'; line-height: 90%; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px\">\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{4}\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"width: auto; height: {5}px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 5px\">\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img style=\"border: none\" src=\"{6}/up_arrow_cir.png\" alt=\"Click to Enter\"/>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t</table>", tileSlideWidth.ToString(), tileSlideHeight.ToString(), Convert.ToString(tileSlideWidth - SLIDE_ICON_CELL_SZ),
                                                         tileSlideHeight.ToString(), Server.HtmlEncode(tile.TileItemLabel).Replace("[NL]", "<br />"), tileSlideHeight, IMAGE_LOC);
                                        break;
                                    case MetroTileType.Horizontal:
                                        tileSlideHeight = tileHeight;
                                        tileSlideWidth = (int)Math.Round(tileWidth * SLIDE_HW_RATIO);
                                        tileSlideExt = (int)Math.Round((tileSlideWidth * SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO) + tileSlideWidth);
                                        tileSlideMargin = "left: 0px;";
                                        tileSlideTable = string.Format("\t\t\t\t\t<table style=\"width: {0}px; height: {1}px; border-collapse: collapse; float: right\">\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"width: {2}px; height: {3}px; font: normal 0.95em 'Segoe UI Semibold'; line-height: 90%; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px\">\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{4}\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"width: {5}px; height: auto; text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px\">\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img style=\"border: none\" src=\"{6}/right_arrow_cir.png\" alt=\"Click to Enter\"/>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n" +
                                                         "\t\t\t\t\t</table>", tileSlideWidth.ToString(), tileSlideHeight.ToString(), tileSlideWidth.ToString(), Convert.ToString(tileSlideHeight - SLIDE_ICON_CELL_SZ),
                                                         Server.HtmlEncode(tile.TileItemLabel).Replace("[NL]", "<br />"), tileSlideWidth, IMAGE_LOC);
                                        break;
                                }

                                // Initialize slide container
                                sb_HTML.AppendFormat("\t\t\t\t<div style=\"background-color: {0}; width: {1}px; height: {2}px; position: absolute; z-index: 5; " +
                                                     "opacity: 0.7; overflow: hidden; {3}\">\n", tile.TileItemForeground, tileSlideWidth.ToString(),
                                                     tileSlideHeight.ToString(), tileSlideMargin);

                                // Insert pre-composed table
                                sb_HTML.AppendLine(tileSlideTable);

                                // Close slide container
                                sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t\t\t\t</div>");

                                // Insert hidden anchor if tile is active
                                if (tileActive)
                                    sb_HTML.AppendFormat("\t\t\t\t<a href=\"{0}\" style=\"display: none\"></a>\n", tile.TileItemURL);
                            }

                            // ** OTHER TILE EFFECTS ADDED HERE **
                        }

                        // End Cell Tile
                        sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t\t\t</div>");

                        // End Row Cell
                        sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t\t</td>");

                        // Set previous row counter
                        prevRow = currentRow;
                    }

                    // Close final row and group table (if tiles exist)
                    if (group.MetroGroupTiles.Count > 0)
                        sb_HTML.AppendLine("\t</tr>");
                    sb_HTML.AppendLine("</table>");
                    sb_HTML.AppendLine();

                    // Get generated JQuery script for tile group
                    sb_HTML.AppendLine(CreateTileGroupScript(group));

                    // Release generated tile group to page content
                    this.litTileGrp.Text = sb_HTML.ToString();
                }
                else
                    throw new DataException(string.Format("Specified Tile Group '{0}' Does Not Exist.", this.TileGroupID.ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

        // TESTED 09/27/2013 - PASSED! - B. Nichols
        private string CreateTileGroupScript(MetroTileGroup group)
        {
            StringBuilder sb_Script = null;

            try
            {
                // The following string is created and formatted in such a way
                // to maintain readability while IN THIS CODE!.

                // Start Scripting Section
                sb_Script = new StringBuilder("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine();

                // SlideTile - MouseEnter event function
                sb_Script.AppendLine("      $(\"div.slideTile\").mouseenter(function () {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendFormat("        var SLIDE_HW_RATIO = {0};\n", SLIDE_HW_RATIO.ToString());
                sb_Script.AppendFormat("        var SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO = {0};\n", SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO.ToString());
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("          if (this != null) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              // Get tile height and width");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var parHght = $(this).innerHeight();");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var parWdth = $(this).innerWidth();");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              // Change tile border (lighten)");
                sb_Script.AppendFormat("              $(this).css(\"border-color\", \"{0}\");", group.MetroBorderHighlight);
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              // Check if tile has a slide");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var chld = $(this).children(\"div\");");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              if (chld != null) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // Set extended slide and css length for SQUARE and VERTICAL tiles");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // SQUARE and VERTICAL");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  var extVal = Math.round(parHght * SLIDE_HW_RATIO);");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  extVal = Math.round(extVal * SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO) + extVal;");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  var cssAttr = { height: extVal + \"px\", opacity: 1.0 };");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // HORIZONTAL");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  if ($(this).attr(\"id\").indexOf(\"hTile\") > -1) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                      var extVal = Math.round(parWdth * SLIDE_HW_RATIO);");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                      extVal = Math.round(extVal * SLIDE_HW_EXT_RATIO) + extVal;");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                      var cssAttr = { width: extVal + \"px\", opacity: 1.0 };");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // Call JQuery animation method");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  $(chld).animate(cssAttr, 250, \"swing\", function () { });");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("          }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("      });");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();

                // SlideTile - MouseLeave event function
                sb_Script.AppendLine("      $(\"div.slideTile\").mouseleave(function () {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendFormat("        var SLIDE_HW_RATIO = {0};\n", SLIDE_HW_RATIO.ToString());
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("          if (this != null) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              // Get tile height and width");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var parHght = $(this).innerHeight();");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var parWdth = $(this).innerWidth();");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              // Change tile border (back to background color)");
                sb_Script.AppendFormat("              $(this).css(\"border-color\", \"{0}\");", group.MetroBorderColor);
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var chld = $(this).children(\"div\");");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              if (chld != null) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // Set normal slide length and css for SQUARE and VERTICAL tiles");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // SQUARE and VERTICAL");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  var extVal = Math.round(parHght * SLIDE_HW_RATIO);");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  var cssAttr = { height: extVal + \"px\", opacity: 0.7 };");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // HORIZONTAL");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  if ($(this).attr(\"id\").indexOf(\"hTile\") > -1) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                      var extVal = Math.round(parWdth * SLIDE_HW_RATIO);");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                      var cssAttr = { width: extVal + \"px\", opacity: 0.7 };");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  $(chld).animate(cssAttr, 250, \"swing\", function () { });");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("          }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("      });");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();

                // ActiveTile - Click Event (URL ReDirect)
                sb_Script.AppendLine("      $(\"div.activeTile\").click(function () {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("          if (this != null) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              // Get hidden anchor tag from div");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              var chld = $(this).children(\"a\");");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              if (chld != null) {");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  // Get URL from anchor tag");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  var url = chld.attr(\"href\");");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("                  window.location.href = url;");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("              }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("          }");
                sb_Script.AppendLine("      });");
                sb_Script.AppendLine();

                // End Scripting Section
                sb_Script.AppendLine("</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return sb_Script.ToString();
        }

        public Guid TileGroupID { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionStringName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am using jquery v2.0.3 and jquery UI v1.10.3

UPDATE: 12/11/2013
Was running through all the languages the site needs to support, and discovered the following (regarding the control mentioned above):

```
Portuguese    -    Not Working
Russian       -    Not Working
Chinese (Sim) -    WORKING!
English       -    WORKING!
Czech         -    Not Working
Dutch         -    Not Working
French        -    Not Working
Arabic        -    WORKING!
German        -    Not Working
Italian       -    Not Working
Japanese      -    WORKING!
Spanish       -    Not Working
```

Possible code page issue? (Stretching here!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow developer finally answered this question on the ASP.NET website. You can find that answer here:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1960248/5600510.aspx?p=True&t=635248678044426022&pagenum=1

Thanks!